# Why must I use + in mongoDB query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am doing the learnyoumongo tutorials to learn mongoDB.

On the third excercise (the **find** tutorial) I couldn't get it to work until i just found the solution. My mistake was that the query needed a "+" in front of the argument.

so `db.coll.find({ $gt: process.argv[2] })` did not work, but `{ $gt: +process.argv[2] }` did.

Perhaps this is a stupid question, but what is that plus sign, and when would I use it?

Also does it play a role in  regular javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+` in this context is an implicit cast to a number.  `process.argv[2]` will be a string. The `+` is simply a quick, easy, and generally safe way to cast it to a number. `$gt` expects a number for comparison rather than a string -- even a numeric string.

Comment: the long form way is `{ $gt: Number(process.argv[2]) }`, afaik the `+` shorthand is identical, and yes this works in node and browser javascript